# UITableView cells with ALAssets images overlap when scrolled

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, alasset

In my ios project I'm using a uicollectionview and custom CollectionViewCells to load local images saved on the device (through ALAssets).

My problem occurs when the user scrolls down and then back up. It seems as though it takes long enough for ALAssets to load the image (I'm not using the thumbnail version) which gets it confused and sets the cell's wrong image. I know for sure that it's the wrong cell's image, as it has already been set in the past with the correct image.

How can I overcome this issue and synchronize the image loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Cancel ALAssets operations connected to each cell inside this function:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
```

in your custom cells class. That should prevent updating image on cell which were reused and which has different content.